# Return value of android:onClick method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a button that declares an `onClick` handler:

```
<Button
    android:onClick="clickHandler"/>
```

Can I specify a return value for clickHandler?

```
public boolean clickHandler(View v) {
    return true;
}
```

There's no problem at all in Android 4.1, but maybe there are some other versions that don't support it. [The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick) say that it should have a void return type, but returning boolean does work (at least with a specific phone and android version).

Disclaimer: I don't like to specify code in the XML, and I'd rather not return a value from this method, but I'm working with legacy code.

Comment: I don't see how it makes sense for it to have a return value. The system is going to call this method, and the return value will not be used since the system (likely) isn't expecting one. If something else other than the system is calling this method, that already smells bad to me and that code should be refactored.

Comment: It is being called somewhere else indeed. I totally share your opinion, I'm just trying to refactor the least possible amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return any type there but it is not used for anything in the framework.

Here's the reference how `onClick` attributes get translated to `OnClickListener`s: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java#3789

The code has been more or less the same since ancient Android era.